# TypeError: this.adapter.add is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, socket.io

I'm using socket.io "^1.7.1", and "socket.io-redis": "^6.0.1"
when I am doing the following

```
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis')

io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: config.server, port: config.port }))
```

then I am getting this error

```
 this.adapter.add(this.id, room, function(err){
               ^

TypeError: this.adapter.add is not a function
    at Socket.join (/Users/Desktop/project/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:242:16)
    at Socket.onconnect (/Users/Desktop/project/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:295:8)
    at /Users/Desktop/project/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:172:16
```

Any idea what's not write in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was doing some research and it turned out that my socket.io-redis version was not compatible with socket.io. I have updated my socket.io version to 2.4.1 and not this issue is resovled.